# convert foreach to lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

I'm new to using lambda notation so please correct my understanding if I'm wrong. Is it possible to rewrite the a for each loop in one statement using lambda? I having the following:

Model

```
public partial class Section
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
    //...
}

public partial class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Foreach

```
List<Section> sections = db.getSections.ToList();
List<Question> questions = db.getQuestions.ToList();

foreach (var section in sections)
{
    List<Question> questionsInSection = new List<Question>();
    foreach (var question in questions)
    {
        if(section.SectionID == question.SectionID)
            questionsInSection.Add(question);
    }
    section.Questions = questionsInSection;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your attempts

Comment: It would also help if you added to your question what it is you are trying to do. Including an example input and expected out put.

Comment: Also are you using EF? If so please show your model classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a previous answer that someone posted that got deleted... This solutions accomplishes what I was trying to do in a single statement.

```
sections.ForEach(s => { s.Questions = questions.Where(q => q.SectionID == s.SectionID).ToList(); });
```

Comment: This is my own post , why the down vote? This is what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Did'nt downvote. Since this does not solve your question but is more details on what you have tried then this should be edited to the question above and not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If Navigation Properties are not an option and you do not want to create new instance of every Section and copy it's properties one by one, you can still replace the inner foreach using LINQ and leave the external foreach as it is:

```
List<Section> sections = db.getSections.ToList();
List<Question> questions = db.getQuestions.ToList();
foreach (var section in sections)
{
    section.Questions = questions.Where(o => o.SectionID == section.SectionID).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Section> sections = questions
                        .GroupBy(x=>x.SectionID)
                        .Select(x=>new Section(){SectionID=x.Key,questions=x.ToList()})
                        .ToList()
```

Comment: This won't have all the other properties of `Section`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Entity Framework and if so set the [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) and just:

```
var sections = db.getSections.Include(s => s.Questions)
                             .ToList();
```

*If this is a one-to-many relationship check: [Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)*

If you are not using Entity Framework then `GroupJoin`  the two tables and project a new `Section`:

```
var result = (from section in db.getSections
              join question in db.getQuestion 
              on section.SectionID == questions.SectionID into sectionQuestions
              select new Section
              {
                  Prop1 = section.Prop1,
                  Prop2 = section.prop2,
                  Questions = sectionQuestions
              });
```

---

If for some reason you do not want to use the Navigation Properties, nor project a new `Section`, your data is big and ypu want to use the foreach then do it this way:

```
var sections = db.getSections.ToList();
var questions = db.getQuestions.GroupBy(item => item.SectionID)
                               .ToDictionary(key => key.Key,
                                             value => value.Select(i => i).ToList());

foreach (var section in sections)
{
    List<Question> selectedQuestions;
    if (efficientQuestions.TryGetValue(section.SectionID, out selectedQuestions))
    {
        section.Questions = selectedQuestions;
    }
}
```

The reason I made this `foreach` more complex is so the questions is stored in a dictionary where the key is the `SectionID`. This way the complexity is of `o(n)` and not `o(n)2` (as when using `foreach` + `Where`)

*But again.. as you see by all the `if` in the explanation.. Best option without doubt is just to use navigation properties*